# What is this brass key-like tool left in my new house?

Tags: tools

I just bought a new home and I'm trying to figure out what this tool is for:

Any ideas?

I think it's for something in the bathroom, but I'm at a loss as to what.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a key for a bathroom doorknob. It comes with certain knobs.

[image]